# Revit API - Copy a Face from the project into a family

Tags: revit-api

I have a Revit Face, think of a RuledFace with holes, or NurbsSurface, maybe. I need a copy of that Face in a new family document.
Currently, I'm tesselating/triangulating the face and put those triangles into my family, which kind of works, but I have these intermediate edges between the triangles, which is very bad in my scenario.
I could not find a way to create e.g. a BRepBuilder with the exact information of the Face element.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to transfer geometry from one Revit document to another is by using the copy and paste functionality provided by the [`CopyElements` method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/7b56b5c2-3aff-f42b-ab47-de1f89a1070f.htm). Examples of using it are provided in the Revit SDK samples **DuplicateViews** and **GenericStructuralConnection**.

Comment: That was a hint in the right direction. I have all the faces I need in a Solid, somewhere. So I can put this solid simply into the family instance. That should work. Many thanks.